# Reevaluating or storing boolean in non-evaluated form in TI-BASIC program

Tags: ti-basic

I'm passing a boolean expression in terms of some variable `I` into a TI-BASIC program that manipulates `I`, but the boolean expression is only evaluated once - at the beginning of the program's execution.

Here is a sample program:

```
Prompt J
0 -> I

Lbl 1
1 + I -> I
Disp I

If J
Then
Goto 2

Else
Goto 1
End

Lbl 2
End
```

(This is not the actual program I'm writing, which is more complicated and thus cannot use a for loop; the above program could obviously be written more elegantly with a for loop.)

We increment `I` by 1, starting with the number 0. After every increment, we check whether `J` is true, and if so, we stop.

If I pass in `J=I≠5`, the program stops after printing `1`.

If I pass in `J=I=5`, the result is not expected. **I intend for the program to stop when `I=5` is true, but instead the program continues indefinitely.** This means that `J` is only evaluated at the beginning of the program.

Is it possible to **reevaluate `J` in every execution of that loop**?

---

I assume that `J` is being replaced with `0` and `1` as soon as it is passed in. To rephrase my question, is it possible to input/keep the boolean expression as an unevaluated string/literal? Then I would just call something like `eval(J)` within the program.

Answer (score 2):

The assumption in your update is correct; The J is being replaced by a numerical value.

The answer to your rephrased question is yes, you can pass an expression, but you have to use a function variable instead of a real variable:

```
Prompt Y1
```

Whenever `Y1` is called, it will re-evaluate, so if you store `I=5` to `Y1`, then `Y1` will return 0 whenever I≠5 and 1 when I=5.

Answer (score 0):

```
DelVar IPrompt J
```

Yes I meant to not put a newline there. You don't need one. Trust me.

```
While not(J
I+1->I
Disp I
End
```

This is your program, optimized. Your problem is that J is never changed after your original prompt, so the loop will go around and around forever. Yes, you can reevaluate J in every iteration, but you do need to actually DO it, if you want your program to work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're using Lbl/Goto loops here; I would advise that if a For loop doesn't work for you, then try to use While or Repeat loops instead. They're neater and faster.

With that aside,

You're incrementing `I` by 1 and checking `J≠0` every time. `I` and `J` are entirely different variables, and they're not going to interact with each other unless you make them interact. If your initial input is `J=0`, then the program will run forever.

> I intend for the program to stop when I=5 is true, but instead the program continues indefinitely.

But there is nothing in the code that checks if `I=5`. You should put an `If I=5` somewhere if you want this to happen.

> Is it possible to reevaluate J in every execution of that loop?

Yes, but you need to manually tell the calculator to do so.

> I assume that J is being replaced with 0 and 1 as soon as it is passed in.

This is not the case. Rather, the `If J` in your code will output FALSE if `J=0`, and TRUE for any other value of `J`.

Also, you don't need the `End` at the end of your program; in TI-BASIC, the `End` command indicates the end of code blocks such as `If:Then` conditionals and `For`/`While`/`Repeat` loops.

I suggest you read here: http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com